# Is there a pattern in these bitshifts?

Tags: file, usb, hex, bit-manipulation, recovery

I have some Nikon raw files (.nef) which were rendered useless during a USB transfer. However, the size seems fine and only a handful of bits are shifted - by a value of -0x20 (hex) or -32 (dec).

Some of the files could be recovered later with another Computer from the same Card and now I am searching for a solution to recover the other >100 files, which have the same error.

Is there a regular pattern? The offsets seem to be in intervals of 0x800 (2048 in dec).

```
Differences between the two files
1. /_LXA9414.dump: 13.703.892 bytes
2. /_LXA9414_broken.dump: 13.703.892 bytes
Offsets: hexadec.

 84C00: 23      03
13CC00: B1      91
2FA400: 72      52
370400: 25      05
4B9400: AE      8E
641400: 36      16
701400: FC      DC
75B400: 27      07
925400: BE      9E
A04C00: A8      88
AC2400: 2F      0F

11 difference(s) found.
```

Here are more diffs from other files:
http://pastebin.com/9uB3Hx43

Comment: Which pattern? In the addresses? (no idea there) Or the values? (obviously a difference of 0x20)

Comment: Yea, obviously 32dec is missing at any point where the data is corrupt. The question meant the addresses. Ie. Any offset interval pattern

Comment: I don't see any usable patterns